# App does not work after adding release method (MediaPlayer)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am a beginner to android and am creating an android app which plays only one song and contains 3 options to start,pause and stop the song. Before adding the release method the app played,paused the song and after adding the release button the app fails to even play the song.

below is the XML code

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start song 1"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/pause_button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="pause song 1"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop_button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="stop song 1"

    />
```

and the java code

```
package com.example.android.musicplayer;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private void releaseMediaPlayer()
{
    if(mediaPlayer!=null)
        mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer=null;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.song);
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button1);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            releaseMediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
    Button pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button1);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    });

    Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button1);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();


        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          releaseMediaPlayer();
}

});
}
}
```

Comment: One issue I see is you have no way of restarting the media player once it's released.  You'll never be able to play anything else once it's complete the first time.

Comment: Though you need to look at the stack trace to know why it's having issues.

Comment: What other methods can i use? I tried putting the create method inside the startButtons onClickListener but the app doesn't open at all.

Comment: You have set some data sources before starting the media player

Comment: elaborate on data sources.